# Android Storage Access FrameWork and hidden files

Tags: android, usb

Im new to Storage Access FrameWork on Android.

I need to be able to access hidden files on an external USB drive plugged into Android using the Storage Access FrameWork.

Im wondering if its possible for an app to access hidden files stored on an external USB drive connected to Android.

It seems in order to access a file, Android must display a dialog box where the user picks a file, giving the app access to only that file.

So if the file is hidden, it will not get displayed in the list of file presented by android to the user, so then the user cant pick the file, then the app wont have permission to access that file.

Is this correct? Is there a way around it?

Thanks

Comment: If someone is in the same situation as me and just needs a file picker that shows hidden files [this project](https://github.com/nbsp-team/MaterialFilePicker) does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Storage Access Framework then you I assume you are using [Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) which launches the system documents picker.

Instead, use [Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE). Then you will receive a `DocumentFile` that represents the *directory* and you can use [DocumentFile#listFiles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#listFiles()) to iterate through all the files including 'hidden ones'.

Comment: Not the same person but I don't get any file or directory to list when I use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE(also I cannot set the category or filter files by mime type).